# How to change the default US keyboard to a Hungarian keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout

I already added Hungarian as a language, but in the keyboard menu settings I don't see any other keyboard available to add or set. I don't want to change the default system language, just the keyboard, and I don't want to change the layout manually key by key.

I'm using 12.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 3):

Just run the following command in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts "['hu', 'us']"
```

If you want only Hungarian keyboard layout, use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts "['hu']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the GUI you can do it like this:

1. Open the **Keyboard** app (accessible through the Dash)
2. Click the **Layout Settings** link in the lower left
3. Click the **+** button on the lower left (below the list of existing layouts)
4. Search for the Hungarion layout you wish and Click **Add**
5. Close the Keyboard app (a keyboard button will show up in the top menu bar that lets you select a layout)

If you wish to remove the US keyboard use the **-** button in the layout list.